# F# filter out only first occurrence from list

Tags: filter, f#, fold

I have a list and I want to remove an element matching some criteria but remove only one element.

```
let items = [1;2;3]

let predicate x =
    x >= 2

let result = items |> List.fold ...
// result = [1;3]
```

How to achieve method returning list with [1;3]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a generic recursive function

```
let rec removeFirst predicate = function
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t when predicate h -> t
    | h :: t -> h :: removeFirst predicate t
```

or a tail recursive one (if you fear a stack overflow)

```
let removeFirst predicate list =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | [] -> List.rev acc
        | h :: t when predicate h -> (List.rev acc) @ t
        | h :: t -> loop (h :: acc) t
    loop [] list
```

Comment: Guard clauses can be nice, but in this case I think they make it more confusing.  I think just `| h :: t -> if predicate h then (List.rev acc) @ t else loop (h :: acc) t` is more clear.

Comment: An advantage of this answer is that it stops processing when the first matching value is reached so it might save a lot of work.

Comment: In the tail-recursive version you could change the `[]` case to return the input `list` instead of reversing the accumulator, which is just the reversed list anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
let result =
    items
    |>List.scan (fun (removed, _) item ->
        if removed then true, Some(item) //If already removed, just propagate
        elif predicate item then true, None //If not removed but predicate matches, don't propagate
        else false, Some(item)) //If not removed and predicate doesn't match, propagate
        (false, None)
    |>List.choose snd
```

The state is a tuple. The first element is a Boolean flag indicating whether we already have removed some item from the list. The second element is an option: Some when we want to emit the item, None otherwise.

The last line takes the second elements from the states and for each of them emits the wrapped value (in case of Some) or does nothing (in case of None).

Comment: This ran the slowest in my tests.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short alternative, which in my testing was faster than the others proposed so far:

```
let removeFirst p xs =
    match List.tryFindIndex p xs with
    | Some i -> List.take i xs @ List.skip (i+1) xs
    | None -> xs
```

Answer (score 0):

Aiming for an intuitive solution.

```
let removeAt index list =
    let left, right = List.splitAt index list
    left @ (List.skip 1 right)

let removeFirst predicate list =
    match List.tryFindIndex predicate list with
    | Some index -> removeAt index list
    | None -> list
```

For performance (long lists).

```
let removeFirst predicate list =
    let rec finish acc rem =
        match rem with
        | [] -> acc
        | x::xs -> finish (x::acc) xs
    and find l p acc rem =
        match rem with
        | [] -> l
        | x::xs ->
            if p x then finish xs acc
            else find l p (x::acc) xs
    find list predicate [] list
```